# Operator Overloading and array handling in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading, little-man-computer

I am writing a Little Man computer simulation and i want to overload the Indexing operator  `[]`. I have create a class called LMC and have done the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class LMC
{
   public:
       LMC();
       void display();
       int& operator[](int index);
       ~LMC();
   private:
       int **array;
};

LMC::LMC()
{
   array = new int*[100];
   for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
       array[i] = new int[3];
   }
   return array;
}

void LMC::display()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100;i++)
    {
       for(int j = 0; j <3;j++)
       {
          array[i][j] = 0;
          array[i][2] = i;
          cout << array[i][j]<<" ";
       }
       cout << endl;
    }
 }
 int& LMC::operator[](int index)
 {
    return array[index][2];
 }

  LMC::~LMC()
  {
     for(int i =0; i < 100 ; i++)
     { 
        delete [] array[i];
     }
     delete [] array;
     array = NULL;
  }

  int main()
  {
     LMC littleman;
     while(true)
     {
         int mailbox;
         int function;
         cout << "What is Mailbox number?" << endl;
         cin >> Mailbox;
         cout << "What is the function you want to use?" <<endl;
         cin >> finction;
         //the function is numbers eg 444 and 698;
         littleman.display();
         littleman[Mailbox] = function;
      }
     return 0;
}
```

I can run the program with no error. When i state that `mailbox = 0` and `function = 123` the is no problem.

This is displayed:

```
0 0 0
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
//continuing to 99
```

This display is wrong. The following must be displayed:

```
0 0 123
1 0 0
2 0 0
//continuing to 99
```

Do i have a logical error or am i overriding the array to display the original and how can i fix it?

Comment: Please save yourself the trouble and use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`  instead of `int**`  for your internal array.

Comment: `0 0 0` Is that the output of `LMC::display()`?

Comment: @Andrey Yes that is the output.

Comment: @TonyTheLion. You must have more experience than me but i did not ask you for a easy way i asked for help with the code given. If i wanted to use a vector i would have but i did not, no disrespect.

Comment: How did you manage to run this code? It is not compilable.

Comment: @Johan: The problem is that Tony is _right_. You need to use `std::vector`, and keep such stuff as you are doing until you know more about C++.

Comment: @JohanDela What Tony suggested is an improvement to your code. Certain parts of it are unacceptable and have to be rewritten. If you're not using standard library, you should know all well that the responsibility is now on you and the approach is much more error-prone.

Comment: If you have requirements that force you to use `int**` then you'll have to either: reimplement (at least) parts of what is already implemented in `vector` or explain what those requirements are. How can we know whatever solution we propose meets these undisclosed requirements? (in other words, please don't make us waste our time trying to help you)

Comment: Also, you're violating the "rule of three". Something you don't need to care about if you had used std::vector in the first place.

Comment: How will it work with a vector. Im not as comfortable with vectors as i am with arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines

```
  array[i][j] = 0;
  array[i][2] = i;
```

in `LMC::display()` destroy the contents of the array you're trying to display.

Furthermore, there's an extra semicolon at the end of `void LMC::display();`, so your code is not supposed to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a number of errors which will not let it compile namely:

- in the `LMC()` constructor, you have `return array;`. Constructors never return anything (they don't even have the return type), so you can not use `return` in them.
- after `void LMC::display()`, you have a `;`, which is an error, because this is not a definition, but implementation. You should omit it and just leave `void LMC::display() { <...> }`
- `void LMC::display()` is missing the closing `}` in the end, right before the `operator[]`.
- in `main()` you have typos in `Mailbox` (capital M in one case, and normal m in another. In C+++ `Mailbox` and `mailbox` are *different* variables) and `finction` instead of function.

As for your problem, you are rewriting the values of the aray in `display()` function:

```
array[i][j] = 0;
array[i][2] = i;
```

That's why you don't see any results.